# libgit2 treebuilder API and on-the-fly packing

Tags: git, libgit2

We're developing a tool that needs to create *very large* git trees containing lots of objects (~10k - 100k). The I/O for the many files corresponding to these objects is going to be a bottleneck, so we're wondering if it would be possible to do a sort of on-the-fly re-packing.
I imagine this done either when doing `git_blob_create_frombuffer()` or when doing `git_treebuilder_insert()`.

Do you think this would be meaningful and feasible?
In case this wouldn't be feasible, do you have any suggestions on how to handle this use case with libgit2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there might be some misunderstanding in what a tree is and how it's created.

Creating a tree should never cause a re-pack. When you create a tree, you already have the objects in the database. Thus the fastest way to create the tree is to leave that data which already exists alone. Creating a pack out of the blobs would mean reading them all in and comparing them. Leaving them be is by definition the fastest thing you can do, as it doesn't involve any work.

At some point it may make sense to expose a way to write objects directly to a packfile, but this is not currently possible.

You speak in the future, which suggests you have not measured or implemented this yet. Until you do so, any other advice would be rather useless as it would have no bearing on what you *are* doing with your code.